# Dependency Injection: what do you lose when instantiating concrete classes in parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection

Generally speaking, my dependencies are abstracted to interfaces, but I will only be using one concrete implementation during non-testing use.  For example, were I to write a `FooService`:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IBarDependency _barDependency;

    public FooService(IBarDependency barDependency)
    {
        this._barDependency = barDependency;
    }

    public FooService() : this (new BarDependency())
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    . . . // code goes here
}
```

Now purists tend to gasp in horror, because I instantiated a concrete class in the parameterless constructor.  I have, in the past, shrugged this off, because I know the only time I will not be using the concrete class is when I am unit testing and mocking dependencies.

While it does couple the `FooService` class to the `BarDependency` class, it's not a *tight* coupling; these classes and interfaces also exist in the same assembly, so it doesn't seem to me like I'm losing a whole lot here, or painting myself into a corner.  I can still easily test the `FooService` class without getting unmanageable code, just by using the constructor that allows me to pass in mocked interfaces.

So the question is: what is actually at risk here?  What am I losing with this sort of pattern that is worth adding an IoC container?

Comment: I use same approach in small projects. DI and other "doing it right" rules usually make small projects overly complex. Sure, it brings lot's of benefits but it's not always worth the hassle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lifetime management, for example. Maybe you use `BarDependency` throughout your code and only want one instance to be alive. You can't do this if every user creates their own instances.

You also have to find all usages of `new BarDependency()` if you ever want to replace it with `new NewBarDependency()`.

A container fixes both problems for you, as then you configure the instantiation and lifecycle of objects in one method, namely where you set up your container.

Comment: So you are suggesting IoC container is better suited for Singleton pattern injection?  That makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you can use a "once per AppDomain" lifetime, so you don't need singletons or static classes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, but if the FooService needs to be accessed by some other developer, the dependency to BarDependency will be basically hidden. In my opinion not only mocking and testing is the reason for using dependency injection, but also a clear indication what is used by certaing classes, and what they are need to work properly.
And maybe I'm to much purist, but when such pattern is ok, then it's easily to go further and end up with a totally tightly coupled and hard maintanable code.

Answer (score 1):

What you lose without dependency injection is the ability to centralize all aspects of the dependency management. Visualizing the dependency graph and managing the lifecycles of your objects is easier when you have all the information in one place, instead of scattered all over the code.

A concrete example would be if you wanted to replace the default implementation of `IBarDependency` used in some, but not all of the classes. Reasoning about which ones to replace is much easier if the dependencies are all wired in the same file or group of files.